# Using State to filter the data of a fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a React native app for a covid form
I'm getting the data from a Json so I've used fetch and .then to get the actually json with the question and save it on a QuestionsState, but when I try to filter the data and get the individual question to save that on a QuestionState, that is not showing on the view, but when I console.log that and press ctrl + s to save en vs code, the individual question appears

the questions code is this

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alejoduke52/covidForm/main/covid-19.json'

const Questions = () => {
  

    const [covidQuestions, setCovidQuestions] = useState([{}])
    const [individualQuestion, setIndividualQuestion] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [countId,setCountId] = useState(1)


    useEffect(() => {

        console.log("cargando use effect")
        
        getData()
        
        
       
      },[])

      useEffect(() => {

        console.log("cargando use effect data unica")
        
        
        getQuestion(1)
       
      },[countId])
      



    const getData = () =>{

      fetch(url)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
          setCovidQuestions(data)
          getQuestion(1)
        })

    }

    const getQuestion = (id) => {

      setIndividualQuestion(covidQuestions.filter(Question => Question.id === id))
      console.log(individualQuestion)
      setLoading(false)

    }


    
    const handlerNextQuestion = () => {
      console.log("jasdjasjdas")
      console.log(individualQuestion)
      //getQuestion(countId)
      setCountId(countId+1)

    } 

    




  return (
    <View>
      {
        loading ? <Text style={styles.loading}>LOADING</Text> : (

          <View key={0}>
            <Text>hello {individualQuestion.question}</Text>

          </View>

        )
         
        
        //jsx
      }

      <Button title="Cargando s" onPress={() => handlerNextQuestion()} />
    </View>
  );
}

export default Questions

const styles = StyleSheet.create({


  loading: {

    fontSize: 40

  }
})
```

**It is very strange cause when I first render the app the state is empty but only when I press ctrl + s, it shows**

Answer (score 0):

`individualQuestion` state is an array you have to use it like

Option 1:

hello {individualQuestion[0].question}

Option 2:

setIndividualQuestion(covidQuestions.filter(Question => Question.id === id)[0])

Comment: Option 1 shows the error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'individualQuestion[0]')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getQuestion(1, data)` instead of `getQuestion(1)`.

You can pass data to `getQuestion` function

```
const getData = () =>{
  fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => {
      setCovidQuestions(data)
      getQuestion(1, data)
    })
}

const getQuestion = (id,data) => {
  setIndividualQuestion(data.filter(Question => Question.id === id))
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code It will give you full functionality:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alejoduke52/covidForm/main/covid-19.json'

const Questions = () => {
    const [covidQuestions, setCovidQuestions] = useState([])
    const [individualQuestion, setIndividualQuestion] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [countId, setCountId] = useState(1)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("cargando use effect")
        getData()
    }, [])

    const getData = () => {
        fetch(url)
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    setCovidQuestions(data)
                    console.log("Data", data)
                    getQuestion(1, data)
                }
            })
    }

    const getQuestion = (id, data) => {
        console.log(data)
        let question = data.find(Question => Question.id === id)
        console.log("Question", question)
        setIndividualQuestion(question)
        setLoading(false)

    }

    const handlerNextQuestion = () => {
        setCountId(countId + 1)
        getQuestion(countId + 1, covidQuestions)
    }

    return (
        <View>
            {
                loading ? <Text style={styles.loading}>LOADING</Text> : (
                    <View key={0}>
                        <Text>hellO</Text>
                        {individualQuestion != undefined ?
                            <View>
                                <Text>{JSON.stringify(individualQuestion)}</Text>
                                <Text>Question: {individualQuestion.question}</Text>
                            </View> : null}
                    </View>
                )
            }
            <Button title="next" onPress={() => handlerNextQuestion()} />
        </View>
    );
}

export default Questions

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    loading: {
        fontSize: 40
    }
})
```

Hope You will like it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here there are two problem which I see

First problem is you are trying to access `covidQuestions` immediately after `setCovidQuestions` inside `getQuestion(1)` function, since setting state in react is always an asynchronous event and takes some time to update the state value. So basically you should not call `getQuestion(1)` immediately after `setCovidQuestions` .

Second, problem I see with the filter you are using, since filter always return an array of filtered questions, even if there is one question, so you can never access `individualQuestion` like `{individualQuestion.question}`, since its an array.

My solution to the first problem would be to remove `getQuestion(1)` after `setCovidQuestions` inside fetch API call and instead you can actually add `covidQuestions` as dependency to your useEffect which runs on change of  `countId` like below

JSX

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("cargando use effect data unica")
        getQuestion(1)
      },[countId, covidQuestions])
```

And for your second problem related to filter mechanism, you can do something like this, while rendering

JSX

```
<View key={0}>
    <Text>hello {individualQuestion[0].question}</Text>
</View>
```